# Can I preview dyed items?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

I have only recently started using dyes in Baldur's Gate 3, but the results were surprising. The effects of a dye with names like '*Harlequin Black and White*', or the differences between swamp green and sage green, are not immediately obvious. (With the former I anticipated a diamond chequered result, but alas!)

| [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- |
| Default colour of the Potent Robe | Harlequin Black and White dye |

**Can I preview the dyeing colours in-game?**

A trial-and-error approach wouldn't be so annoying if the game were to load a little quicker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a highly requested feature but is not currently possible.

---

You can find examples of what some of the clothes look like on the Baldur's Gate 3 subreddit, though.  For example, see

[40 Dyes on Homely Clothes](https://www.reddit.com/r/BaldursGate3/comments/161431m/40_dyes_on_homely_clothes/)
[40 Dyes on Adamantine Scale Mail](https://www.reddit.com/r/BaldursGate3/comments/160x4c9/40_dyes_on_adamantine_scale_mail/)
[40 Dyes on Lae'zel's Underwear](https://www.reddit.com/r/BaldursGate3/comments/161vkou/40_dyes_on_laezels_underwear/)

If you search the subreddit you can find lots of other examples.

Comment: The BG3 Wiki (*not* the Fextralife one) also has a fair number of examples: https://bg3.wiki/wiki/Dyes

Answer (score 0):

Why a way to preview item dyeing would be preferable is because the dyes are limited, and some are very rare. But there is a mod which makes these items limitless, and make the process of *save-scum-dying* to preview items at least a lot less time-consuming:

[Everybody dyes - unlimited dyeing](https://www.nexusmods.com/baldursgate3/mods/936) on Nexus.

Of course, having to modify your game just for the purpose of seeing what colour scheme the next cryptically designated potion will produce might not be worth the investment (but, just in case, [here](https://www.nexusmods.com/baldursgate3/mods/668) is a mod to allow you to keep earning achievements which will otherwise be disabled by default).